# WinDirStat Save Report Option

Tags: windows-7, file-management, disk-space, windirstat

When running WinDirStat against a drive, I'd like the option to save the report so that I can look at it later while "offline" away from the system it was run on.

I've looked around the program and can't see this option. Am I missing something, can this be done with WinDirStat?

If it can't be done, is there a way similar to WinDirStat that will allow me to save the results of a drive space scan to delve into them at a later date?

Comment: It looks like this has been an open bug since 2008 http://sourceforge.net/p/windirstat/feature-requests/8/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

WinDirStat does have an email report feature but I've never been able to get it to work.

Like I said in my comment, the export report feature is still an open issue.

[SpaceSniffer](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/download.html) is a similar tool that has an export feature.

Comment: I believe the e-mail report feature just sends a canned e-mail to a user telling them to clean up their home directory, etc.

Comment: I gave the aforementioned SpaceSniffer a spin it does allow you to export a scan as a text file. Not sure if that will meet your needs or not.

Comment: The e-mail feature opens a mail with the canned message inside, but also a list of the folder with their sizes. From what I observed, it takes the list as-is, i.e. things that are expanded will be expanded with the subdirectories&files in the mail, and those that are closed will appear without any further details besides the total size. I have a standard installation of Thundebird as default mail program, and the e-mail report feature worked directly.

Comment: Glad to hear it works with Thunderbird and not just Outlook. This is the message you get if you don't have any desktop email software installed on the system you run it on: "No Microsoft Outlook profiles have been created. In Microsoft Windows, click the Start button, and then click Control Panel. Click User Accounts, and then click Mail. Click Show Profiles, and then click Add."

Comment: I can use email Report function. However, the report only has total space of indivual subfolder but without file counts. I thought the report will look as like the final statistic list as on UI.

Answer (score 2):

The report can be generated by selecting "Report" > "Send email to owner". For those contributors and readers saying that they can't get that option to work (as it's greyed out): You have to manually select an item in the list (which can be the root element) to be able to generate a report. The amount of information shown is determined by what's shown in the list. The more items are expanded there, the more information will be shown in the e-mail.

[image: WinDirStat path selected]

[image: sample]

Answer (score 0):

The Report option works for me if I close down Outlook fist. Running WinDirStat 1.1.2.80 and Outlook 2016 on windows 7

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Linux program: `ncdu` (NCurses Disk Usage) on windows

ncdu works very well to load saved output.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncdu
- https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu

Not really a GUI, but still console browsable.

You can save output with `-o`

```
ncdu /mnt/c -o my_c_drive.ncdu
```

You can then view with `-f`

```
ncdu -f my_c_drive.ncdu
```

I am able to use this with Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install

```
PS C:\Users\user> wsl --status
Default Distribution: Alpine
Default Version: 2

Windows Subsystem for Linux was last updated on 11/3/2021
WSL automatic updates are on.

Kernel version: 5.10.60.1
PS C:\Users\user> wsl
Computer:/mnt/c/Users/user$ ncdu --version
ncdu 1.15.1
```